# Obfuscate Silverlight library using Dotfuscator

Tags: silverlight, obfuscation, strongname, dotfuscator

I'm attempting to use Dotfuscator 4.7.1000 to obfuscate a Silverlight library that is strongly named. When I attempt to do so, I get the following error message:

> External type not found
>   System.Data.Services.Client.LoadCompletedEventArgs,System.Data.Services.Client,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.

I have tried adding this assembly to the GAC, and have tried adding user defined assembly load paths to the configuration to locations where this assembly is located to no avail.

I then tried adding System.Data.Services.Client to the input assemblies and ran it again. This time it gets further, but ultimately I get:

> Warning: Password protected Strong Name files are not supported
>   sn returned 1.

It appears as though it is attempting to run sn.exe on System.Data.Services.Client.dll with my local key. I've tried excluding this assembly from any obfuscation tasks, but it continues to do so.

Is there something I'm missing when trying to obfuscate this library? Is there some other way to directly point it to the DLL it can't seem to find that I don't know about? Or can I include the DLL in the project without it trying to obfuscate the Silverlight library?

And for the moment, please no suggestions on alternate obfuscators. My company has a license for Dotfuscator and I'd like to get this running using that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I must have been screwing up my user defined assembly load paths. As soon as I re-added the path to the Silverlight 4.0 client DLLs everything worked without having to reference System.Data.Services.Client.